# How Do I make my fragment go fullscreen with another fragment as it's parent not activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-windowmanager

Usually if fragment is contained within activity, we can just do this :

```kotlin
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
     .add(android.R.id.content, OurFragment())
     .commit()
```

But what about from another fragment though ? they don't even have `android.R.id.content`
And i know it is not impossible because `DialogFragment` exists. The question is how ? is there a way other than overriding dialogfragment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the answer

first you need to add `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` on `manifest.xml`

then on your fragment

```kotlin
class YourFragment : Fragment(){

    lateinit var mTopView : View
    lateinit var windowManager: WindowManager

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val LAYOUT_FLAG: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
        }
        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LAYOUT_FLAG,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )

        windowManager = requireActivity().applicationContext
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

        val li = requireActivity().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        mTopView = li.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null)

        windowManager.addView(mTopView, params)
        return mTopView
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        windowManager.removeView(mTopView)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a fragment without an activity it is not possible you can do one thing that you can make an activity full screen(if you also do not need the action bar you can set theme as `AppTheme.NoActionBar` ) and then by setting the fragment's layout as match parent you can also set fragment inside a fragment you can do this by placing tht super child fragment into the layout of the parent activities child fragment's layout. Use this inside the fragment in which you want inflate another fragment

```
android.app.FragmentManager fm = fragment.getChildFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
 .add(android.R.id.content, OurFragment())
 .commit()
```

Comment: But that requires the super fragment to be as big as it's activity. What i want to do is to make ```OurFragment``` attach it's lifecycle to the super fragment with view as big as it's activity like what ```DialogFragment``` basically does